# What can cause an Azure Cloud Service's Disk Write/Read to spike unexpectedly?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

We have a simple worker that picks up messages from a queue and runs a few queries. We don't ever write to the disk ourselves but we do have diagnostics turned on in the roll settings.

Once in a while the the disk write/read spikes and the worker becomes unresponsive. What is the role trying to write to the disk? On the surface it doesn't appear to be a crash dump because those tables and blobs are still empty. Are our diagnostics configured improperly?

Here's an example of a spike we saw recently. It was writing for over an hour!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling remote desktop support in the role configuration in the Azure portal.

Once the problem resurfaces, log in via RDP and start Resource Monitor. The Disk tab should be able to pinpoint disk IO usage by process and by file.

Comment: We were able to track down the issue using this approach. We discovered the service was writing MBs of data to a page-file due to a severe memory leak in the code. The service had essentially run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling storage logs should tell you exactly what are those reads and writes on the disk.

[image]

Comment: Won't those diagnostics only tell me what things are being written to the blob storage? I believe the disk read/write we're seeing is happening on the Cloud Service's local disk. I would have assumed that writes to blob storage show up only as Network Out.

Comment: Those logs won't tell you anything really.  They're best for "outside" access to storage, not internal VM stuff that happens in Windows

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a very open ended question and is very hard to predict.  Your Cloud Services are ultimately Windows machines and what's happening on Windows can (usually) only be monitored by something inside Windows.

It is very possible that a Windows Update related task was running.  Those may cause spikes in disk R/W

We typically advice users who use [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) and want to know what causes CPU/Memory/other issues to install CloudMonix agent on their machines as it captures running processes, their memory and CPU utilizations and can show process that caused a spike.  Usually spikes in disk R/W are correlated to spikes in CPU usage.

Note, if the spike was caused by your own code, you'll need to use profilers such as RedGate's ANTS performance profiler or Jetbrains dotTrace or some such to determine the ultimate root cause.

HTH